# How to implement updating of a table in a DB from different threads with Hibernate-based DAOs?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, spring

I have a class, let's call it `UserGenerator`. It contains several injected DAOs (spring singleton beans), let's say `UserDao` and `OrganizationDao`.

`UserGenerator`'s purpose is creating users for a new organization. So, what I want to have is:

```
@Transactional
public void createOrganizationWithUsers(Organization org, int userCount) {
    organizationDao.persist(org);
    //run (userCount / 100) threads, let them do something like
    // userDao.persist(new User(randomParams())); 

}
```

The problem is that the organization is created successfully, but userDaos throw hardly-debugged exceptions and as I understand, they state that Hibernate session is closed (or, maybe, something else):

```
//this line (only if runs in a new thread) produces the exceptions 
//shown below (it tries to retrieve the organization by its Id)
getSession().createCriteria(getDomainEntityClass()).add(Restrictions.eq("id",id)).uniqueResult();
```

```
//Exceptions
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2235)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1597)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:328)
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/ error occured while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:220)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:451)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:350)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:135)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:104)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:259)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1182)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:194)
    ... 36 more
```

What is the correct way to do this task?

P.S. I know that the design is far from perfect, but I just curious how to achieve the goal even if it worth to redesign the system and avoid the problem.

Comment: Do you use usermanaged or containermanaged transactions? And take a look at the hades-project http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/hades it will autogenerate DAO-Objects for you. It mey be included into spring one day. I guess you use usermanaged transactions. So try to bind your session to a threadlocal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the following:

- Hibernate `Session`s are not thread-safe
- Spring-managed transactions are thread-bound

So, I guess each thread should start its own transaction (e.g. with `TransactionTemplate`) and obtain its own `Session` via `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. But note that in this case the whole operation would be not transactional.